# How to perform discriminant analysis in R software?

Tags: r, discriminant-analysis

I would like to perform discriminant analysis in R language. Please let me know the code  and related packages for it.

Comment: That's a pretty vague question which is likely to elicit generic answers without much interest for future readers. Would you mind giving more information on the context of your study or application? Also, do you mean Fisher, linear, quadratic discriminant analysis?

Answer (score 4):

You can try the `lda()` function in package **MASS** which should come with *all* R installations as it is a Recommended package.

Load the package via:

```
library("MASS")
```

Then read the help page for `lda()`

```
?lda
```

paying particular attention to the example section. When back at the prompt you can run the examples using `example(lda)`